# Fiji error: "No images file selected" when using a macro that calls the plugin 'Average Images'

Tags: plugins, macros, imagej

I would like to create a macro with Fiji, that then I would run by using matlab.

I would like to average 3 images by using the [*Plugins>Stacks>Average Images*](http://fiji.sc/Average_Images).

I used first *Plugins>Macro>Record...* to get an idea what to use. Here is the result:

```bsh
run("Average Images", "add=D:\\Corinne\\diabetes_paper_meas\\2013_01_29\\Measurement.007_cb\\Measurement._cb_frame0_pvar-8bit_combined.tif add=D:\\Corinne\\diabetes_paper_meas\\2013_01_29\\Measurement.007_cb\\Measurement._cb_frame1_pvar-8bit_combined.tif add=D:\\Corinne\\diabetes_paper_meas\\2013_01_29\\Measurement.007_cb\\Measurement._cb_frame2_pvar-8bit_combined.tif");
saveAs("Tiff", "D:\\Corinne\\diabetes_paper_meas\\2013_01_29\\Measurement.007_cb\\test.tif");
```

However, even when I run this macro I got an error: No images file selected. However, in Fiji you do not need to open any images to run the plugin but you add the files through a window interface...
So of course, since just running the macro is not working I get the same error when I use the following macro:

```bsh
file = getArgument;
if (file=="") exit ("No argument!");
setBatchMode(true);
file_vasc = file;

file_vasc_frame_0 = file;
file_vasc_frame_1 = replace(file, "\\_frame0_pvar-8bit_combined.tif", "_frame1_pvar-8bit_combined.tif");
file_vasc_frame_2 = replace(file, "\\_frame0_pvar-8bit_combined.tif", "_frame2_pvar-8bit_combined.tif");


run("Average Images", "add=file_vasc_frame_0 add=file_vasc_frame_1 add=file_vasc_frame_2");
file_vasc_out = replace(file, "frame0_pvar-8bit_combined.tif", "_vasc_averaged.tif");
saveAs("Tiff", file_vasc_out);
```

Somebody has an idea what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Average Images* plugin is using dialogs in a non-standard way and therefore is not scriptable: when running the plugin in Fiji with the macro recorder active (*Plugins>Macros>Record...* and then *Plugins>Stacks>Average Images*), you will see Fiji complain as soon as you add a second file to the list:

> Duplicate keyword:
>
> > Command: "Average images"
> >
> > Keyword: "add"
> >
> > Value: /path/to/your/file
>
> Add an underscore to the corresponding label in the dialog to make the first word unique.

This clearly is a bug in the plugin (it makes multiple use of the same `OpenDialog` thereby recording duplicate keywords in the macro recorder). You can report it via *Help>Report a bug*, however I fear that this plugin is not actively maintained at the moment.

In any case, there is a simple alternate way to average images in ImageJ without requiring this plugin, using the *Image>Stacks>Images to Stack* and *Image>Stacks>Z Project...* commands:

```js
setBatchMode(true);
open("/path/to/first-image.tif");
open("/path/to/second-image.tif");
run("Images to Stack", "name=stack title=[]");
run("Z Project...");
saveAs("Tiff", "/path/to/new-file-name.tif");
```